# C# Regex split() without removing the split condition character

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

I am splitting a `string` with regex using its `Split()` method.

```
var splitRegex = new Regex(@"[\s|{]");

string input = "/Tests/ShowMessage { 'Text': 'foo' }";

//second version of the input: 
//string input = "/Tests/ShowMessage{ 'Text': 'foo' }";

string[] splittedText = splitRegex.Split(input, 2);
```

The `string` is just a sample pattern of the input. There are two different structures of `input`, once with a space before the `{` or without the space. I want to split the `input` on the `{` bracket in order to get the following result:

- /Tests/ShowMessage
- { 'Text': 'foo' }

If there is a space, the string gets splitted there (space gets removed) and i get my desired result. But if there isnt a space i split the string on the `{`, so the `{` gets removed, what i dont want though. How can i use `Regex.Split()` without removing the split condition character?

Comment: Use [`@"\s*(?={)"`](https://ideone.com/QASSyI).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The square brackets create a character set, so you want it to match exactly one of those inner characters. For your desire start off by removing them.

So to match it a *random count* of whitespaces you have to add `*`, the result is this one`\s*`.

- `\s` is a whitespace
- `*` means zero-or-more

That you don't remove the split condition character, you can use lookahead assertion `(?=...)`.

- `(?=...)` or `(?!...)` is a lookahead assertion

The combined `Regex` looks like this: `\s*(?={)`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/9229688) is a really good and detailed documentation of all the different `Regex` parts, you might have a look at it. Furthermore you can test your `Regex` easy and for free [here](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to not include the curly brace in the match you can put it into a look ahead

```
\s*(?={)
```

That will match any number of white spaces up to the position before a open curly brace.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. But how do the `[ ]` affect my regex expression? Didnt understand it in this specific case.

Comment: Will this not over-split the string thanks to that pipe character ?

Comment: @L.Guthardt The square brackets are for creating a character set.  So `[\s|{]` will actually match any whitespace the pipe character or the open curly brace.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I've fixed that.

Comment: @juharr I was asking because i tried the code with the brackets `[\s*(?={)]` and it removes the `{` again. Why though if it matches the position before the curly brace?

Comment: @L.Guthardt Again the brackets are for a character sets so you are asking it to match one of the characters inside and except for `\s` they lose their special meanings.

Comment: @juharr Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular string split, on "{" and trim the spaces off:

```
var bits = "/Tests/ShowMessage { 'Text': 'foo' }".Split("{", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
bits[0] = bits[0].TrimEnd();
bits[1] = "{" + bits[1];
```

If you want to use the RegEx route, you can add the { back if you change the regex a bit:

```
var splitRegex = new Regex(@"\s*{");

string input = "/Tests/ShowMessage { 'Text': 'foo' }";

//second version of the input: 
//string input = "/Tests/ShowMessage{ 'Text': 'foo' }";

string[] splittedText = splitRegex.Split(input, 2);
splittedText[1] = "{" + splittedText[1];
```

It means "split at occurrence of (zero or more whitespace followed by {)" - so the split operation nukes your spaces (you want), and your { (you don't want) but you can put the { back with certainty that it will mean you get what you want

Comment: Yes adding it back or going the default `string.split` way is possible and produces my result, but that wasnt what i was looking for. Its more complex than i showed, just some plain sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
var splitedList = srt.Text.Replace(".", ".#").Replace("?", "?#").Replace("!", "!#").Split(new[] { "#"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

This will split text for .!? and will not  remove condition chars. For better result just replace # with some uniq char. Like this one for example '®' That is all. Simple as it is. No regex.split which is slow and difficult due to many different task criterias, etc...

passing-> **"Hello. I'am dev!"**

result (split condition character exist )

1. "Hello."
2. "I'am dev!"